# Using Linq with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am so sorry for asking such a thick question. I need to sort the characters in  a string using vb.net.

I normally use C#.

This is my code:

```
Dim val1() As Char = txtInput.Text.Trim.ToArray
val1 = val1.OrderBy(c >= c).ToArray()
```

Tells me that 'c' is not declared.

I have imported these:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You're still using c# syntax for your lambda expression. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx for details of Lambda expressions in vb.

Comment: hi, quite some differences I see. Thanks

Comment: I've actually added that as an answer too now. I needed to check that my VB was correct before posting it since I don't use VB that much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still using c# syntax for your lambda expression. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx for details of Lambda expressions in vb.

In your case its as simple as

```
val1 = val1.OrderBy(Function (c) c ).ToArray
```

Comment: No prob. I'm intrigued as to why you made the other answer the accepted answer though.

Comment: Hi, mistake. I wanted to award the earliest answer and mis-read it as the other one. sorry

Comment: Ah. I wasn't trying to rep beg, just was trying to work out if I should have done something better. :)

Comment: Its OK. It was my fault and deserved the reward

Answer (score 1):

To sort the characters of a string with the result being a string:

```
    Dim s As String = txtInput.Text.Trim.OrderBy(Function(c) c).ToArray
```

And if you want the result to be a character array:

```
    Dim val1() As Char = txtInput.Text.Trim.OrderBy(Function(c) c).ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you don't really need Linq or lambda to do this. You can use `ToCharArray` and sort (in place) that array :

```
Dim chars = someString.ToCharArray
Array.Sort(chars)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that.  I guessed I could have but wanted to know how to do it in linq. Thanks